# How to solve Maximum call stack size exceeded Error in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get data from firebase using axios. I'm using vuex store to handle all my data .

I've this two actions to get the data and store it :

```
nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
        return axios
          .get("https://nuxt-blog.firebaseio.com/posts.json")
          .then(res => {
            const postsArray = [];
            for (const key in res.data) {
              postsArray.push({ ...res.data[key], id: key });
            }
            vuexContext.commit("setPosts", postsArray);
          })
          .catch(e => context.error(e));
      },
      setPosts(vuexContext, posts) {
        vuexContext.commit("setPosts", posts);
      }
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code but it gives me this errors :

[Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uMoY.png)

[errors on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTjQu.png)

Comment: In my case, it was fixed by using the same name for both component `name: "Sample"`  property and `<Sample />`.

Comment: I received this error when introducing a new component into a template. Wrapping the component with Nuxt's `<client-only></client-only>` cleared the error. I'll trace the actual culprit in the future.

Comment: Happened again. This time, I was calling a component inside itself. It causes recursion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should put only POJO objects into vuex. Most likely you are putting some heavily nested object into it. E.g. `res.data` contains some non Pojo object that u are putting into vuex

Comment: I've minimized the object and i get this error ```Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established ```

Comment: @AymanTarig no idea, too little info and thats not a place for it. If u have new issue and your current one solved, mark it as solved and open a new question with information